# Issue appending JSON data to document

Tags: jquery, json

I currently am having problems appending certain data to my html document. I am currently appending three different API's to the document but the third API is the one I am having issues with. I call on to the third API to retrieve the information after the other two have been called later on in the document. The point of the third API is to retrieve the geolocation after another API has retrieved the list of IP addresses from the databases for demographic purposes.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?callback=?&key=myAPIKey&format=json&ip="+ ipAddressfromAPI, 
            {
            format: 'json'
            }).done(function(json){
                $('#countries' + y).append(json.countryName);
                console.log(json.countryName);
            });//end of JSON
```

Now when I console.log(json.countryName), I find all the countries the ipAddresses are coming from but they are not being displayed. For more information purposes, the id '#countries' + y are created through a loop by the length of the amount of ip Addresses found. But the issue is just that the country names are not being displayed.

Comment: Why do you have `format=json` in the URL *and* `format: 'json'` in the parameter?  You only need to set it once.

Comment: Use `$.each` in your json response to append all the countries

Comment: Please show us the loop where `y` is being obtained from.

Comment: $('#countries' + y) is just a location of the divider which has already been created so that it can match the country info to the appropriate divider, so when you look at the html it looks like countries0, countries1, countries2, etc...

Comment: client.run(allData, function(res){
  for(var y=0; y < res.result.length; y++){

Comment: @user3673288: Are you doing this AJAX call *inside* that loop? If so, that's your problem.  A classic JavaScript problem.  When the callbacks of the AJAX run, the loop is finished, and `y` has been incremented past the final element.  All the callbacks use the same `y` variable, so when they run `$('#countries' + y)` doesn't exist (they are all referencing the same `y`, which is incremented past the last element).

Comment: Somehow it feels like there's something you're hiding. Including the loop with the rest of your code in the question would be more useful to both you and us. Don't you think so?? :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your code look like this?:

```
for(var y=0; y < res.result.length; y++){
   //Creating the #countries +y element and appending it to the DOM
   $('<div id="countries' + y +'"></div>').appendTo('body');


   $.getJSON("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?callback=?&key=myAPIKey&format=json&ip="+ ipAddressfromAPI, 
        {
        format: 'json'
        }).done(function(json){
            $('#countries' + y).append(json.countryName);
            console.log(json.countryName);
        });//end of JSON
}
```

In this case the variable y inside the getJSON done function has a value of res.result.length.
That means while the getJSON request ist asynchrounusly waiting for the response to start the done function, your for loop ist still executing and increasing the y variable to the max value.

Then the Response from the AJAX call  is firing the done function and you try to append the countryName to an invalid Element.

If this is the case then try somthing like this code:

```
for(var y=0; y < res.result.length; y++){
   //Creating the #countries +y element and appending it to the DOM
   $('<div id="countries' + y +'"></div>').appendTo('body');

   (function(){

      var z = y;

      $.getJSON("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?callback=?&key=myAPIKey&format=json&ip="+ ipAddressfromAPI, 
        {
        format: 'json'
        }).done(function(json){
            $('#countries' + z).append(json.countryName);
            console.log(json.countryName);
        });//end of JSON
   })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `console.log( json.countryName )` is displaying anything!!

Change:

```
$('#countries' + y).append(json.countryName);
```

To:

```
$('#countries' + y).append(json[y].countryName);
```

And this has to be in the loop.

Comment: It does....I saw the list of the country names  within the console, adding json[y].countryName will just display the letters one by one

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the `json` .. what is the structure? Post it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, assuming that `console.log` log displays what you expect in the console, there are two possible issues which could cause the contents of `json.countryName` not to be appended to the document.

1. `y` isn't defined or is set to an incorrect value so the id in the document isn't found
   or
2. There is no element in the dom with the id you are looking for